# Jasper preview in JFrame won't open when project is deployed to the tomcat server

Tags: java, jasper-reports

so I have a small web application that generates a pdf file from jasper reports. The jasper preview works fine when running it through eclipse, but when I export the project into a war file and deploy it to the server, the jasper preview does not open anymore, although it still generates the pdf file. I've been looking for solutions online but I can't seem to find one.

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String outFileName = request.getParameter("directory") + "\\" + request.getParameter("reportName") + ".pdf";
    String fileName = request.getParameter("directory") + "\\" + request.getParameter("reportName") + ".jasper";
    String realPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if ("printJasper".equals(request.getParameter("action"))){
        try {
        parameters.put("P_ASSD_NO", request.getParameter("assdNo") == null ? "" : request.getParameter("assdNo"));  
        Connection conn = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, parameters, conn);
        JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(fileName, request.getParameter("directory") + "\\" + request.getParameter("reportName") + ".jrprint", parameters, conn);
        JRExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outFileName);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
        exporter.exportReport();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jasper report");
        JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);

        frame.add(viewer);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work?

> Additional info - using:
>   Tomcat 8, Java 8

Comment: Okay, how is the frame suppose to open (I presume you want it) on the client side?  It's possible that the JVM on the server is running in headless mode, which won't allow for a UI to be generated

Comment: It's supposed to open a window that contains the report data. Can you please explain what headless mode means?

Comment: Headless mode means - it has no screen, keyboard or mouse (generally). A web server is "some computer, some where, which serves web pages" (more or less), which you connect to other the network. There is no way that the web server would be able to open a window on a client machine - we'd all be knee deep in advertising crap if it could. You should be sending the PDF back to the client bia the `HttpServletResponse` and allowing it to decide "how" to display it

Comment: You could make the code work, but it would open always on server and I guess you are not interested in this, you need to export the report in a format of your/client choice (pdf,html ecc) and send it as a file via http